# Add static block or phtml file to magento product page via custom layout xml

Tags: php, xml, magento

I want  to add a reference to my product page which i have done in catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bannerref') ?>
```

Then found below section of catalog.xml where my reference is located

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

and added the following code:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="bannerref" as="bannerref" translate="label">
            <label>banner ref</label>
        </block>
```

I then wanted to add to this reference with custom layout to show a certain banner for certain categories and have this applied through the parent category with "custom layout xml".

I was hoping the below code would add the static block into that reference but it doesn't work. It Does work with reference="content" so there is no issue with the static block just trying to put content in my reference from here.

```
<reference name="bannerref">
     <block type="cms/block" name="productbanner">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>productbanner</block_id>         </action>
     </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: I think there may have just had a spelling mistake somewhere i've got this working now.

Comment: perhaps you haven't cleared the cache? Also there is a whole stackexchange site dedicated to magento: http://magento.stackexchange.com/